# Unable to uninstall PHP 7.3 on CentOS 7

Tags: php, centos, uninstallation

My webserver's PHP was not working. I planned to reinstall PHP on the server. However, not able to uninstall PHP. When I tried to find the PHP from the terminal, I able to find it from php -v. Even when I tried to find the installed package using yum, I can see PHP is installed there. But when I tried to yum remove php*, it does not uninstall the php.

Here is my terminal output.

```
[root@web5 ~]# yum list installed | grep php
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
oniguruma5php.x86_64                   6.9.6-1.el7.remi               installed
php.x86_64                             7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php-cli.x86_64                         7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php-common.x86_64                      7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php-gd.x86_64                          7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php-json.x86_64                        7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                     7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php-opcache.x86_64                     7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php-pdo.x86_64                         7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php-pecl-mcrypt.x86_64                 1.0.4-1.el7.remi.7.3           installed
php-xml.x86_64                         7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php73-php-common.x86_64                7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php73-php-json.x86_64                  7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php73-php-xml.x86_64                   7.3.27-1.el7.remi              installed
php73-runtime.x86_64                   2.0-1.el7.remi                 @remi-safe
rh-php70.x86_64                        2.3-1.el7                      @centos-sclo-rh
rh-php70-php-bcmath.x86_64             7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-cli.x86_64                7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-common.x86_64             7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-devel.x86_64              7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-fpm.x86_64                7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-gd.x86_64                 7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-json.x86_64               7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-mbstring.x86_64           7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-mysqlnd.x86_64            7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-opcache.x86_64            7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-pdo.x86_64                7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-pear.noarch               1:1.10.1-3.el7                 @centos-sclo-rh
rh-php70-php-process.x86_64            7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-pspell.x86_64             7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-xml.x86_64                7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-xmlrpc.x86_64             7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-php-zip.x86_64                7.0.27-2.el7                   installed
rh-php70-runtime.x86_64                2.3-1.el7                      @centos-sclo-rh
sclo-php70-php-mcrypt.x86_64           7.0.27-1.el7                   @/sclo-php70-php-mcrypt-7.0.27-1.el7.x86_64
wbm-php-pear.noarch                    2:1.6-1                        @virtualmin-universal
[root@web5 ~]# yum -y remove php*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
No Match for argument: php-17-7-19.ini
No Match for argument: php-pac.txt
No Packages marked for removal
[root@web5 ~]# php -v
PHP 7.3.27 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2021 10:32:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.27, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
[root@web5 ~]# yum -y remove php*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
No Match for argument: php-17-7-19.ini
No Match for argument: php-pac.txt
No Packages marked for removal
```

I am right now a bit confused about my next step. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the asterisk is interpreted by the shell, did you try
yum -y remove 'php*'?

Comment: Than i ask kindly to upvote, even if it is a oneline answer.